# Set what Console.ReadKey gets with Console.SetIn?

Tags: .net, console, console-application

I know you can do `Console.SetIn(new StringReader("new input"));` and then `Console.ReadLine();` will return "new input" but is there a way to do this for `Console.ReadKey()`?

Comment: I really doubt you can do that, because TextReader is an abstract class.

Comment: @Andrey - Fixed question to be StringReader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Console.ReadKey() uses the native console API, ReadConsoleInput() to read input.  You can't redirect that.

Other than by the obvious way, write a public static method that calls ReadKey() unless you want to return something else.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would rather want [Console.Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) as `ReadKey` waits for a keystroke while Read just reads the next character.

Comment: yea, I actually want to wait for the next keystroke (I think)... I want to do something like "Press any key to continue" in my console app.